# Поиск по классу и логическое НЕ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, операторы

Добрый день. Вопрос такого характера:
Я, нахожу класс для чтобы задать свойство элементу

```
if($('.class')) {
    $('.class').css('top', 10);
}
```

Но при этом мне нужно еще одно условие, чтобы на странице не было другого класса

```
if($('.class') && !$('.class2') ) {
    $('.class').css('top', 10);
}
```

Пробовал и так

```
$('.class1' && !'.class2')
```

Как сделать такое условие, я по разному пробовал не выходило. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: `if ($('.class'))` всегда возвращает `true`, так что это некорректная проверка даже для одного класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Селектор jQuery `$(...)` всегда возвращает объект-обертку вокруг некоторого количества DOM-элементов, даже если этих элементов ноль. Результат селектора, как булевское значение, соответствует `true`. Вам следует проверять количество найденных элементов.

```
if ($('.class').length > 0 && $('.class2').length == 0) {
    $('.class').css('top', 10);
}
```

или эквивалентное

```
if ($('.class2').length == 0) {
    $('.class').css('top', 10);
}
```

так как в отсутствие элементов с классом `class` операция `$('.class').css('top', 10);` ничего не делает.

Comment: Еще бы немного пояснений на русском добавить, почему так